# Estimating conditional probability distribution from samples

Tags: distributions, conditional-probability, nonparametric, multivariate-regression

I have three continuous variables, $X$, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. All three are correlated. For a given value of $X$, the conditional probability distributions of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are typically bimodal. I'm given a set of samples with measurements for the three quantities, and would like to come up with a way to predict the conditional probability distributions of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ (or at least the median and $1\sigma$ error bars) for future measurements of $X$. How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Do you mean a bivariate conditional distribution of $(Y_1,Y_2)$?

Comment: That's right. I think multivariate conditional KDE might do it, but I'm wondering if that's the best way.

Comment: Multivariate Gaussian mixture model?